# Настройка логирования django

Tags: django, settings, логирование

Как настроить логирование django так, чтобы каждый уровень записывался в отдельный лог. К примеру есть

```
LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,
    'formatters': {
        'log_formatter': {
            'format': '{levelname} {asctime} {module} {message}',
            'style': '{'
        }
    },
    'handlers': {
        'debug_handler': {
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'class': 'logging.FileHandler',
            'filename': 'myfile',
            'formatter': 'log_formatter'
        },
        'info_handler': {
            'level': 'INFO',
            'class': 'logging.FileHandler',
            'filename': 'myfile',
            'formatter': 'log_formatter'
        },
        'warning_handler': {
            'level': 'WARNING',
            'class': 'logging.FileHandler',
            'filename': 'myfile',
            'formatter': 'log_formatter'
        },
        'error_handler': {
            'level': 'ERROR',
            'class': 'logging.FileHandler',
            'filename': 'myfile',
            'formatter': 'log_formatter'
        }
    },
    'loggers': {
        'myapp': {
            'handlers': ['error_handler', 'warning_handler', 'info_handler', 'debug_handler'],
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'propagate': False
        }
    }
}
```

В файл лога DEBUG записывается всё, в INFO всё кроме DEBUG и т.д.
Можно сделать так, чтобы в DEBUG только DEBUG, в INFO только INFO и т.д.?

Comment: Пожалуй, надо обратить внимание на секцию [filters](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/logging/#filters).

Comment: Уже сделал именно так до вашего ответа. Вопрос забыл закрыть)